# I have a problem when i try to access the image /assets in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, yaml, pubspec

[This is an error when I run the program, so I am a newbie in this language](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvVIX.png)(Click to see an image)

[This is my file "pubspec.yaml ", I think I corrected every syntax and space, but it still happens this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OjOR0.png)(Click to see an image)
[And this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/STb80.png)

Comment: Also check the spelling. Is it `asset` or `assets` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code hope its help to you.

Make sure you have create assets folder in your project working directory, put your images in assets folder and write below code in your `pubspec.yaml` file.

Refer adding assets in your project [here](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/assets-and-images)

Your pubspec.yaml file

```
assets:
    - assets/
```

Your Widget:

```
Image.asset('assets/human.jpg'),
```

Comment: Thanks, sir, I fixed my error, I created the wrong place for my assets folder

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to add your image in asset folder in your project directory?

Answer (score 0):

1- make sure you write image path correctly

2- write this commend in terminal

```
flutter pub get
```

or if you use vsCode ope pubspec.yaml and click Ctrl + s

Answer (score 0):

Change your pubspec.yaml file

from

```
 - assets/human.jpg
```

to this

```
assets:
    - assets/
```

and your

```
child : Image(
   image : AssetImage("assets/human.jpg")
   )
)
```

and finally make sure your space before asset

```
 (2 empty spces or 1 tab)    assets:
  (4 empty spces or 2 tabs)      - assets/
```