# Not able to load image in flutter package

Tags: flutter, dart

I've created a flutter package and images are inside images folder.

```
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  # To add assets to your package, add an assets section, like this:
  # assets:
  assets:
    - images/
    - images/location_pointer.png
```

I'm trying to load this image:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Image.asset(
          'images/location_pointer.png',
          width: 22.0,
          height: 44.0,
          fit: BoxFit.fill,
        ));
}
```

I've created a project and importing a package inside it:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  abc_pkg:
    path: /Users/mosh/Documents/flutter proj/abcPackage/abc_pkg
```

I'm able to load the package when run this project but not able to load the images inside the package.

```
======== Exception caught by image resource service ================================================
The following assertion was thrown resolving an image codec:
Unable to load asset: images/location_pointer.png

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      PlatformAssetBundle.load (package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:224:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      AssetBundleImageProvider._loadAsync (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:675:14)
<asynchronous suspension>
Image provider: AssetImage(bundle: null, name: "images/location_pointer.png")
Image key: AssetBundleImageKey(bundle: PlatformAssetBundle#092c6(), name: "images/location_pointer.png", scale: 1.0)
====================================================================================================
```

Comment: Try to refer my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71349744/13997210) hope its help to you.

Comment: Can you try adding the package name in the Image.asset for example: `Image.asset('icons/heart.png', package: 'my_icons')`

Comment: tried that too. Nothing is working.

Comment: Including package name work for me. Of course you will also need to add assets in `pubspec.yaml`
`Image.asset('icons/heart.png', package: 'my_icons')`

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure all your images are saved inside a directory called 'images', which is inside a directory called 'assets'.
2. Update your pubspec.yaml as follows:

```html
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  # To add assets to your package, add an assets section, like this:
  # assets:
  assets:
    - assets/images/location_pointer.png
```

3. Update your dart file as follows:

```html
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Image.asset(
          'assets/images/location_pointer.png',
          width: 22.0,
          height: 44.0,
          fit: BoxFit.fill,
        ));
}
```

Comment: Still same error.

Comment: where you make folder of images. I mean in which directory @mohsin

Comment: its in main dir. assets/images

Answer (score 0):

> please try this code. and make an image folder in the same
> directory where you have the lib folder
>
> in your pubspec.yaml file

```
 flutter:
    
   uses-material-design: true
    
   assets:
      - images/
```

> and in your dart file

```
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Image.asset(
          'images/location_pointer.png',
          width: 22.0,
          height: 44.0,
          fit: BoxFit.fill,
        ));
}
```

Comment: Its in the same directory. Same error

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that you add assets truly in the pubspec.yaml file just add the name of your package to the package field of image.asset
like bellow:

```
Image.asset(
            e.flagUri!,
            width: 40,
            fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
            package: 'igmu_package',// this is pacakge name
          )
```